# Let $f: (\Bbb Z_{28}, +)\to(\Bbb Z_{16}, +)$ be a group homomorphism such that $f(1)=12$. Find $\ker f$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, group-homomorphism

Let $f: (\Bbb Z_{28}, +)\to(\Bbb Z_{16}, +)$ be a group homomorphism such that $f(1)=12$. Find $\ker f $.

1- $\langle 2\rangle $

2-$\langle 4\rangle $

3-$\langle 7\rangle $

4-$\langle 1\rangle $

I think first of all there is no group homomorphism with $f(1)=12$ because we know that every homomorphism between cyclic groups sends generators to generators . But in this case $12$ is not generator for $(\mathbb{Z}_{16}, +)$ because $(12,16) \neq 1$ .

Comment: Hint: What is the additive order of $12 \bmod 16$ ?

Comment: An isomorphism sends generators to generators. A homomorphism need not. It might even send everything to the identity. You should look at what $12$ generates in the codomain.

Comment: Every **isomorphism** of a cyclic group sends a generator to a generator. Not all homomorphisms are isomorphisms.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\begin{align}
\color{red}{12+12}\pmod{16}&=f(1)+f(1)\\
&=f(1+1)\\
&=f(2)\\
&=\color{red}{8}\pmod{16},
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
\color{green}{8+12}\pmod{16}&=f(2)+f(1)\\
&=f(2+1)\\
&=f(3)\\
&=\color{green}{4}\pmod{16},
\end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}
\color{blue}{4+12}\pmod{16}&=f(3)+f(1)\\
&=f(3+1)\\
&=f(4)\\
&=\color{blue}{0}\pmod{16}
\end{align}$$

Thus $\ker f=\langle 4\rangle$.

Answer (score 2):

$f: (\Bbb Z_{28}, +)\to(\Bbb Z_{16}, +)$  be a group homomorphism.

Since, $1$ is a generator of $\Bbb Z_{28}$, ${\rm Im}(f) =\langle f(1) \rangle=\langle 12\rangle$ cyclic subgroup of $ \Bbb Z_{16}$

$$|{\rm Im}(f)|= {\rm ord}(12)=4$$

Then by first isomorphism theorem, $\Bbb Z_{28} /\ker (f) \cong{\rm Im}(f) $

Hence, $|\ker(f) |=28/4=7$

So, $\ker(f) $ is a cyclic subgroup of $\Bbb Z_{28}$ generated by an element of order $7$.

And, $\Bbb Z_{28} $ an element of order $ 7 $ is $4$.

Hence, $\ker(f) =\langle 4\rangle$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $f(2) =8\neq 0, f(7)=4\neq 0, f(1)=12\neq 0$ and $f(4)=0$ so the answer is $\mbox{ker}f =<4>.$

Comment: Although this is correct, it feels kind of like cheating. *Assuming the question is set up correctly*, this is the answer. But everything is nice and small and we *can* check it is set up nicely!